# PHPwebsocket and HTTP in the same application

Tags: php, apache, web-services, websocket, apache2

Is there an easy way to have a PHP file handle both http requests and websocket connections in the same application?

I want to be able to write something along the lines of

```
if (REQUEST_TYPE == WEBSOCKET)
{
// handle web socket
} else {
// handle HTTP request normally.
}
```

Alternatively is there a way to run an HTTP server from a PHP script.

Ex:

```
$server = new HTTPServer();
$server->run(8080);
```

Comment: PHP isn't the one that accepts the request, it is the server that does, which PHP then is run on. You could write your own HTTP server, but PHP isn't really designed to handle that well. Why not just have the normal HTTP server on 80 and a separate PHP script that is listening to your socket for it's own traffic..